# is it possible to save audio using avspeechsynthesizer?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avspeechsynthesizer

> ***avspeechsynthesizer***

when I'm converting text to speech.
And I want to save that audio file, but I'm not able to save that audio  using **avspeechsynthesizer**.

Comment: They have outputChannels. So you can hook to some where you like.

Answer (score 0):

To dive a little deeper the `E.Coms` comment, the `AVSpeechSynthesis.h` file provides the following information about the `outputChannels` variable:

> Specify the audio channels to be used for synthesized speech as described by the channel descriptions in AVAudioSession's current route.
>
> Speech audio will be replicated to each specified channel.
>
> Default is nil, which implies system defaults.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
open var outputChannels: [AVAudioSessionChannelDescription]?
```